# Extract domains from deployed serverless endpoints

Tags: serverless-framework

After running a serveless deploy command, I would like the retrieve the domain name of the deployed endpoint(s) for further usage in other services. The best I've come up until now is to grep the `sls info` output.

e.g. 
`sls info --stage integration | grep GET - | head -1 | egrep -o 'https?://[^ ]+' | awk -F[/:] '{print $4}'`

Is there a better, less hacky way, of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](https://github.com/weixu365/serverless-scriptable-plugin) plugin.

In your `serverless.yml`

```
plugins:
 - serverless-scriptable-plugin

custom:
  scriptHooks:
    after:deploy:finalize:
      - scripts/postDeploy.js
```

And in `postDeploy.js`

```
const getStackOutputs = async () => {
  const provider = serverless.getProvider('aws');  
  const { stage, region } = provider.options;
  const stackName = provider.naming.getStackName();
  const result = await provider.request(
    'CloudFormation',
    'describeStacks',
    { StackName: stackName },
    stage,
    region,
  );

  const outputsArray = result.Stacks[0].Outputs;

  const outputs = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < outputsArray.length; i++) {
    outputs[outputsArray[i].OutputKey] = outputsArray[i].OutputValue;
  }

  const hostname = new (require('url')).URL(outputs.ServiceEndpoint).hostname;
  console.log(hostname);
};

getStackOutputs();
```

Another option is [this plugin](https://github.com/sbstjn/serverless-stack-output) but you'll need to use a forked version as described [here](https://github.com/sbstjn/serverless-stack-output/issues/25#issuecomment-488948405).